# How to I DISABLE DefaultTyping. Is it disabled by default

Tags: java, spring-boot, jackson, polymorphism

I need to ensure that the application I am writing has no Jackson XML/JSON vulnerabilities (CSV's). All the discussions I have seen talk about how to manage it! I want it OFF.

I am using the latest Jackson version 2.10.0 and the latest Spring boot 2.1.9 and Spring 5.2.0 but I have to justify my use of Jackson and I do not require any polymorphic behaviour.

The doc says I need to use activateDefaultTyping(). This sounds as if it turns it ON. Do I need to use activateDefaultTyping and implement PolymorphicTypeValidator to prevent it? Do I need this to prevent ALL polymorphic behaviour?

I have read lots of articles on managing the behaviour but I am still unclear what the default behaviour is. If it is polymorphic by default I need to turn if OFF.

Comment: If you're asking what the opposite of the [`ObjectMapper`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.10/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ObjectMapper.html) method [`activateDefaultTyping()`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.10/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ObjectMapper.html#activateDefaultTyping-com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.jsontype.PolymorphicTypeValidator-) is, then it would obviously be method [`deactivateDefaultTyping()`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.10/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ObjectMapper.html#deactivateDefaultTyping--).

Comment: Dam! I missed that one! I did not pick up on the pattern 'acctivate/deactivate' for the interface to XmlMapper. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You are vulnerable if you accept input from third parties, outside your application, in JSON format through your external API, and in which input you accept fields of type Object (or other widely implemented classes like Serializable). Then a potential attacker could send (almost) anything, including widely available classes (so called gadget classes), available on your classpath, whose constructors or setters execution (upon instantiation by Jackson at deserialization time) could result in dangerous effects on your system.

In order to be vulnerable, you need to have your Object field annotated with

`@JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.CLASS, include = JsonTypeInfo.As.EXTERNAL_PROPERTY, property = "@class", visible = true)`

or use

`ObjectMapper.enableDefaultTyping()`

or

`ObjectMapper.activateDefaultTyping()` from Jackson 2.10.0

This will tell Jackson to deserialize the incoming json into the specific type specified by `@class`.

Otherwise, whatever data is sent will be deserialized into a key-value map by default.

So by default the "default typing" is OFF.

The `activateDefaultTyping()` you've mentioned should be used only in  to be used in combination with a custom validator to define yourself in a decoupled way what types you allow for deserialization.

In shortest: if you want it OFF and don't need polymorphic deserialization, don't use `@JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.CLASS)` or don't enable it specifically.

You can also call

`ObjectMapper.deactivateDefaultTyping()` to be sure it's not used, but note that using @JsonTypeInfo on your classes will not be affected by this call.

Comment: Thanks. I have added ObjectMapper.deactivateDefaultTyping() to ALL instances of the Object Mapper. NexusIQ seem happy with this so I am happy.